# Is flashing a ROM made for a very similar model to mine possible?

Tags: rom-flashing, custom-roms, samsung

Is it possible that flashing a custom ROM made for another android model could work for me? I'm just wondering this because I have one of those rare models that only a few providers sold, but is very hardware similar to some of the more popular and better supported models. So if I flashed a ROM built for a very similar model to mine would it brick the device?

I'm quite the beginner so if you want to check it out here's my model: SGH-I87D (Samsung Galaxy Ace Q with gingerbread 2.3). I really don't mind taking some chances because it's just my old phone and it was a pretty crappy one at that. So if anyone could give me some tips that would be awesome; oh right and "long live the n00bs".

PS: I've already rooted it so that's not a problem.

Comment: Related: [Can I install any ROM for my Android device?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/35925/16575) / [Why is it that Android still can't be installed as regular OS?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/20364/16575) / our [rom-flashing tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/rom-flashing/info) / our [rom tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/rom/info)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding custom ROMs for re-branded devices](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/128536/finding-custom-roms-for-re-branded-devices)

Answer (score 2):

Possible? Yes. Dangerous? Extremely.

Depending on how similar the model is, you could have it work fine, not work fine, brick, or, in extreme cases, perma-brick.

If you're willing to take the chance, that's fine, but understand that you could do serious damage to your device if you do.