# Installation of Operating System Comparison with that on a Laptop

Tags: installation

If I buy a laptop of Dell, HP, Lenovo or Sony I could install any (meant for Laptop) variant of Linux or Windows on any of these devices, quite easily, without having to risk bricking (completely useless) of the device. Also, for example, Ubuntu is able to find out drivers for most I/O devices on any laptop.

But when comes to Android, why is this process so complex and has a serious warning like things can go very wrong. Also, why is that many IO devices on mobile like a fingerprint reader, etc don't work when OS is installed?

Given that, mobile phone has much bigger userbase, I  expected it to have more support from the community. What is lacking? When Ubuntu can pulloff in most laptops, why can't Google (they too want every mobile to use latest Android version) try to do it?

Also, regarding the security updates why it has to be delivered by the phone manufacturers, instead of Google (like in the case of Windows or  Ubuntu on laptop). There are warnings that custom OS installation won't get any security updates on android (Why Google lets this happen? Why can't they do as Ubuntu does? Why don't they provide an Android that can be installed on any device with ease?).

Comment: You can find parts of your answer via the [installation tag-wiki](/tags/installation/info). Read e.g.: [Can I install Android on my non-Android device?](/q/6849/16575) and especially [Why is it that Android still can't be installed as regular OS?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/20364/16575)

Comment: Also see this: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/205072/bootloader-bios-flashing-rom-and-correlated-risks-why-android-devices-are-more