# Why does Android OS need custom ROMs for OS upgrades?

Tags: updates, rom-flashing, custom-roms, lg, lg-optimus-l5

I have a discontinued LG L5 E455 Android phone that came with Android 4.1.2 OS.

I am forced to upgrade the OS because most of the apps I need to install are not compatible with this version of OS, according to Google Play.

I tried to upgrade the OS through the update option in the Android interface, it did some magic but the Android version is still the same.

I could not find any LineageOS ROM that was created for this phone.

- Is it only possible to upgrade the Android OS by a custom ROM? If so, why?
- Is it possible to install the official Google versions?
- Why does it not work like in Linux distributions that can be installed on almost any PC?

Comment: Related: [Can I install a ROM made for a different device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/35925/16575) // [Why is it that Android still can't be installed as regular OS?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/20364/16575)

Answer (score 0):

Your phone is from 2013 - quite old to be expecting software updates. Hence it's quite unlikely that you would get a major Android version update from LG (maybe security updates if you're lucky). Custom ROMs are maintained by their respective devs giving a bit of extra life for your device.

As for the third question, the answer here is very compehensive - [Bootloader/BIOS, flashing ROM and correlated risks. Why Android devices are more brickable than PCs?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/205072/bootloader-bios-flashing-rom-and-correlated-risks-why-android-devices-are-more)