# Why is there not a utility which builds lineage OS for different devices?

Tags: lineageos, multiple-devices, builds

I've been using Ubuntu on different old computer hardware of mine, and it's wonderful how easy it is to install and how portable it is between different devices.

I have an 8-year old Samsung Android tablet which no longer receives updates, so using the internet on this device is a security risk. I assumed that I would be able to install a non-manufacturer specific version of Android on my tablet, and that this would be comparatively easy as installing Ubuntu on a computer.

So I had a look around and I found lineage OS, and I was surprised to see that it's very much device specific (and unfortunately for me there are no recent builds for my device). I did a little reading into why this is, and I've understood from this that there are two main reasons why it's not to possible to install a single version of lineage OS on many different devices, and that the builds must be device specific. My understanding is that firstly the machine language that processors use varies more across Android devices than it does in desktop and laptop CPUs, and secondly that SoC architectures do not come with a BIOS, which is necessary to inform the installer binary what hardware exists on the chip.

My question is about the second part of the problem to do with the BIOS; it seems to me that this is a straightforward problem to solve. I envisage a utility on my computer which recognises my Android device like how adb does. This utility could then get the hardware setup that exists on my device, either by directly interacting with the phone if this is possible, or by referencing the device's model number against some online database and downloading the information from there. The utility would then be set up to compile lineage OS based on the information that it now has about my device, and I can then copy over the device specific binary and install. That is, the compilation process is moved from a set of different developers who provide support for specific devices, down to a user friendly utility which builds a device specific OS.

So my question is, has this idea been considered? I'm pretty certain this utility doesn't already exist, so then I would also ask, what are the main reasons that would make this difficult to implement?

(and I guess I have a secondary question which is; have I correctly understood this problem? Perhaps I'm missing something in understanding why lineage OS builds are device specific. If this is the case, I would appreciate having this explained in more detail)

Comment: Please see: [Can I install a ROM made for a different device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/35925/16575) // [Why is it that Android still can't be installed as regular OS?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/20364/16575) // [Can I install any ROM for my Android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/35925/16575) In short: Android isn't "installed", but it's a device-specific "image" that gets flashed. So it's not possible to have a "universal installer".

Comment: @Izzy Yes I understand that, my question is 'why is there not linux utility that builds an android image for different devices?', I'm not asking the questions that have been asked in the links you posted. Please can you read my question again and consider unlocking it?

Comment: "there are two main reasons why it's not to possible..." - No. The main problem as I see it is proprietary drivers/implementations that aren't available/installable standalone, intentionally so. Work on these is non-trivial and can't be automated.

Comment: That said, a "universal" Android image already *kinda* exists for modern devices, enabled by Project Treble and in the form of GSIs.

Comment: @Joe Realize that building from source requires [decent resources](https://source.android.com/setup/build/requirements). Historically building for Android is a bespoke activity, see: [Bootloader/BIOS, flashing ROM and correlated risks. Why Android devices are more brickable than PCs?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/205072/3573) also see [How to boot Ubuntu persistent live USB on Android?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/220677/3573). With Project Treble ports have become easier (not easy) but you'll still need a supported device (there are apps to check Treble support in Play Store).

Comment: @Joe ROM development is off-topic here. If you want a build bot, become a developer and DIY - this will answer all your questions. embedded devices are not personal computers, it makes no sense to compare android with some linux distro. If your question is about **why** (and not **how**) we can re-open

Comment: @alecxs, yes I assume that because this doesn't exist it must be difficult to do, and I'm interested in learning about what the difficulties are. I'm not making a request for someone to develop this software.

Comment: from linked question: *"drivers are sometimes/often proprietary [...] difficulties due to those proprietary parts"* (hope this explains)

Comment: @alecxs, thank you for your help. I have already found the comments on this post helpful. If my question is unlocked, those comments could be posted as answers, and I could comment on them (for example, not all drivers are proprietary, so would it be possible for a buildbot to exist in these case? Is there some other obstruction?). Would you be able to reopen my post now? I've also received an upvote.

Comment: I have asked mods but I don't have admin rights on this

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/LineageOS/comments/p6p1y4/where_are_proprietary_blobs